# What is the difference in depth calculation of grease pencil between viewport and render (EEVEE)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

When drawing grease pencil strokes on the surface of a mesh, in the viewport everything looks fine, the stroke is rendered over the geometry, but when I render the scene, the stroke seems to be slightly behind the geometry.

Why does render calculate depth differently from the viewport ?

(Cycles don't have the issue)

Viewport :

[image: Viewport]

Render :

[image: Render]